# React HOC rendering sibling nodes without parent node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to create a Higher-order React component that renders several, sibling nodes, without including a parent node?

I'm currently using `React.cloneElement` this to render children elements *with* a parent element.

```
const RenderChildren = (props) =>
    React.cloneElement(props.children, children.props);

<RenderChildren>
    <div>
        <div>Child One</div>
        <div>Child Two</div>
    <div>
</RenderChildren>
```

---

How can I modify `RenderChildren` to render children elements *without adding an additional DOM node*? If any of the children are React components (as opposed to React elements) I would like to pass all of the props to the child elements.

```
const RenderChildren = (props) => ...

<RenderChildren>
    <div>Child One</div>
    <div>Child Two</div>
</RenderChildren>
```

Comment: It's not really supported. See this issue thread for details on why: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for `<React.Fragment>` added on React@16 or the shorthand `<> </>` which is currently not supported for several compilers

Further reading: https://devdocs.io/react/react-api#reactfragment;

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not have HOC. HOC is a function that takes a component and returns a component. You just have a component that works with child react **elements**.

You could use `React.Children.map` combined with `React.cloneElement` to accomplish this task.

**Warning! Not sure it works on React@15**

```js
const RenderChildren = ({children, ...props}) =>
      React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, props))

const App = () => (
  <RenderChildren className="everybody-likes-pink-boxes">
    <div> Child One </div>
    <div> Child Two </div>
  </RenderChildren>
)

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.everybody-likes-pink-boxes {
  background-color: pink;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">App Goes Here</div>
```